# Find out on which version of numpy a function was added

Tags: python, numpy

Simple question: consider `numpy`'s [`histogram_bin_edges()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram_bin_edges.html). Version `1.15.2` contains this function while version `1.14.1` does not.

Is there a simple way to tell **when** (on which version) a new function was added to `numpy` without having to go through the source?

Comment: The [release notes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html) are your best bet (it is unfortunate that the docs don't list a "version added" for functions).

Comment: That's a simple solution. Would you like to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: Some function docs do note when they were added, or when some new parameter was added.  It may not be routine, especially in older versions.  `np.histogram` has a number version notes.